# Single class instance C++

Tags: c++, class

Is it possible to create a class which could be constructed just one time? If you would try to create an other instance of it, a compile-time error should occure.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a singleton.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern  I must urge you though to very seriously consider whether a singleton really makes sense for your application.  99% of the time a singleton is used, it should not be.

Comment: However, the singleton will just return the same instance for all creation queries. Probably this is even more useful that receiving exception.

Comment: AFAIK there is no option to make such class with compile time error. But there is a popular pattern called 'Singleton' for making such class that preventing instancing. You can easily google tons of examples.

Comment: @rafdp: Why do you want this? This smells like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147331).

Answer (score 6):

Instantiation is dynamic, at run time. Compilation errors are at compile time. So the answer is no, it's not possible to get a compilation error on any second instantiation.

You can however use a singleton, but do consider very carefully whether it's really needed.

Answer (score 1):

The classes with only one instances are called singleton classess,

There are many ways to perform that.  The simplest is shown below

```
class MySingleton
    {
    public:
      static MySingleton& Instance()
      {
        static MySingleton singleton;
        return singleton;
      }

    // Other non-static member functions
    private:
      MySingleton() {};                                 // Private constructor
      MySingleton(const MySingleton&);                 // Prevent copy-construction
      MySingleton& operator=(const MySingleton&);      // Prevent assignment
    };
```

Comment: rafdp asked for example of compile-time error, this is not an answer.

Comment: @Yarg If you will try to create more than one instances of class MySingleton then tis will give compilation error, this is what rafdp asked.

Comment: How about `static MySingleton& OtherInstance()
    {
      static MySingleton anotherSingleton;
      return anotherSingleton;
    }`

Comment: @Yarg If you are saying the class definition could be modified to create another instance, then of course.  But I think the OP was talking about a scenario where the class was designed so that USERS of the class would get a compile error.  I think it's reasonable to assume these users wouldn't modify the class to get around the restrictions.

Comment: @Jaguar: The code is returning the reference. So there is no way to demonstrate compile time error.`MySingleton &a = MySingleton::Instance();
     MySingleton &b = MySingleton::Instance();` Both a and b will be reference to the single static instance `singleton`

Comment: I found this solution:
`class T_
{
    public:
    T_()
    {}
}; '

'#define T struct OBJECT_OF_CLASS_T_HAS_ALREADY_BEEN_CREATED {}; \
 T_'
 
'int main()
{
    T a; 
    T b;   
}`

Answer (score 0):

Why compile error? You just need to implement Singleton design pattern, I think. 
Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)