# Embedded firmware : how to exchange objects between files in C++?

Tags: c++, object, uart, firmware

I am used to developping embedded firmware in C, and my programs are always organized as follows :

1. Application files, which deal with the specificities of the project (e.g. I need to light a LED when the battery is low)
2. Fonctionnal files, which deal with the communication with other components (e.g. I initialize a temperature sensor and I communicate with it)
3. Low level files, which deal with low level peripherals (e.g. UART, I2C, SPI, timers, etc.)

What I normally do is : I call the low level files in my application and fonctionnal files, so that if I need SPI to communicate with a sensor, I simply have to include "spi.h" and use the functions "spi_write" and "spi_read" which are defined here.

Now I have to work on a firmware developped in **C++**. Peripherals are stored in files and **defined as classes** (e.g. the UART class is in "uart.cpp" and "uart.h"). if I want to communicate with UART, I have to instanciate an UART object.

I am not very familiar with C++, I am learning while developping. My main concern is : how can I use an unique instance of a class in all my files ?

For example, I need to print debugging information everywhere. I am pretty sure instanciating an UART object in each file is not a good option. I have tried instanciating an UART object before the main but then all files would have to include "main.h" which I think is not a good option as well.

What is normally recommanded in this situation ? How would you do it ?

Thanks. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single class instance C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361908/single-class-instance-c)

Comment: This question is a bit too broad. Answering how you should organize your code is not really suited for a SO post, and is also subject to a lot of opinion (which is off-topic here).

Comment: When you say "_I simply have to include "spi.h" and use the functions "spi_write" and "spi_read" which are defined here_", do you really mean that they are defined in the header file? One usually declares the functions in the header files and define them in the `.c` (or `.cpp`) files.

Comment: As suggested by RicoRico, the Singleton pattern is probably the way to go. 
When implemented, you will access the unique instance with something like:
 
UART::GetInstance()

Comment: Singletons are probably not a good way to go. If you have two or more UARTs (or GPIOs, SPI, I2C, CAN etc. devices) you would have to start duplicating your singleton class for each device. Instead, you could create the unique instances in your main as normal objects on the stack and then pass them into the classes that need them as references. This is a form of dependency injection and works very well also in embedded code. If you have a nice layer of abstract interface classes, you can also easily test your code without access to the actual hardware.

Comment: @Bert OK thank you I will try your option. 
Let's say I declare a class "Temperature_sensor" with methods and attributes to manage the communication with a sensor. What would be the best solution to deal with the UART class if I want to print debug information when using Temperature_sensor ? Do I add an UART object in theTemperature_sensor attributes ? Or is it better to pass it as an input argument of the class methods that require it ? 
Would the UART object be declared as a reference or a pointer ?

Comment: @JackOfHearts Since you create all objects in your main() (so they are unique and live until the end of the program's run time), you need to pass them into the objects that should use them. If you pass them in as references or via their address doesn't matter. If you call all methods that need the UART from main(), you can also decide to pass them into the methods that need it. It doesn't matter. The important part is that the ownership always remains at main() and classes and methods only use that concrete object you created in main().